# IOS App Stuck on white screen after splash screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

Hi So i recently deployed an app on the app store. It was launching just fine locally in Expo go without any errors but when I download it from the app store it opens up shows the splash screen for like a sec and then has a blank white screen and stays there. Any ideas what could be wrong. It's my first app so I'm not sure where to even start. Its a react native expo project.

Expo SDK 46.0.10

below is my package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.18.9",
    "@expo-google-fonts/inter": "^0.2.2",
    "@expo-google-fonts/nunito-sans": "^0.2.2",
    "@expo/config-plugins": "^5.0.1",
    "@fawazahmed/react-native-read-more": "^2.3.6",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.2.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.12",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.2.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.1.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.5",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "chalk": "^5.0.1",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^2.2.0",
    "email-validator": "^2.0.4",
    "expo": "^46.0.10",
    "expo-app-loading": "~2.1.0",
    "expo-auth-session": "~3.7.1",
    "expo-av": "~12.0.4",
    "expo-calendar": "~10.3.0",
    "expo-camera": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-dev-client": "~1.2.1",
    "expo-firebase-analytics": "~7.1.1",
    "expo-font": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~13.3.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-media-library": "~14.2.0",
    "expo-permissions": "^13.2.0",
    "expo-random": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.16.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.14.5",
    "expo-video-thumbnails": "~6.4.0",
    "firebase": "^9.9.3",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "nanoid": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-country-region-selector": "^3.6.1",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.5",
    "react-native-action-button": "^2.8.5",
    "react-native-axios": "^0.17.1",
    "react-native-bouncy-checkbox": "^2.1.10",
    "react-native-bouncy-checkbox-group": "^0.1.0",
    "react-native-country-codes-picker": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.2.5",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.16.3",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.37.3",
    "react-native-image-viewing": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-keyboard-manager": "^6.5.4-4",
    "react-native-maps": "0.31.1",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-multi-selectbox": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-onboarding-swiper": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "5.4.24",
    "react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.9.1",
    "react-native-select-dropdown": "^1.11.0",
    "react-native-shimmer-placeholder": "^2.0.8",
    "react-native-skeleton-placeholder": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "react-query": "^3.39.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.1",
    "reanimated-bottom-sheet": "^1.0.0-alpha.22",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-persist-expo-filesystem": "^2.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "throttle-debounce": "^5.0.0",
    "uuid-random": "^1.3.2",
    "valid-url": "^1.0.9",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
}
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './redux/reducers';
import Routes from './navigation/Routes';
import { QueryClientProvider, QueryClient } from 'react-query';
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';
let store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk)); 

export default function App() {
  LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Setting a timer']);
  LogBox.ignoreLogs(['EventEmitter.removeListener'])
  const queryClient = new QueryClient({
    defaultOptions: { queries: { refetchInterval: false, staleTime: Infinity } }
  });

  return ( 

    <Provider store={store}>
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <Routes />
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </Provider>

  )

}
```

the the routes component

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { SignedInStack } from './navigation';
import { SignedOutStack } from './navigation';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { userAuthStateListener, } from '../redux/actions/auth';

import AppLoadingScreen from '../screens/AppLoadingScreen';

const Routes = () => {
    
    const user = useSelector(state => state.auth)
    const dispatch = useDispatch(); //get the dispatch from the redux state

    useEffect(() => {
    
            dispatch(userAuthStateListener());

    }, [])

    if (!user.loaded) {
        return <AppLoadingScreen />
    }

    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            {
                user.currentUser !== null ?
                    <SignedInStack />
                    :
                    <SignedOutStack />
            }

        </NavigationContainer>
    );

}

export default Routes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This should be a comment but my rating is still low).

It's hard to tell without some crash logs but it looks like a bootstrapping error. some potential culprits that come to mind:

- your conditional for hiding the splash screen is incomplete and some operation hasn't finished executing (check any async operations like loading fonts)
- if you have any other bootstrapping logic between rendering the app and the first screen, go through that as well.

My suggestion would be to include your `App.tsx` code or, ideally, some crash logs.

Comment: Not getting any errors unfortunately. I have attached more code up until it loads the first screen.

Comment: Depending on whether the logic should flow towards `SignedInStack` or `SignedOutStack` -- is there any conditional render in that initial component? Like `if (condition) return null`

Comment: Also have you tried using React Native Debugger? It's super helpful in situations like these because you can go to the exact component that's not rendering and see the values of state/prop variables

Comment: I only have the `if (!user.loaded) {
        return <AppLoadingScreen />
    }`  which would show a loading screen. Other than that it should at least go to the signed out stack. Okay I'll have to try the debugger to see Thanks!
It's annoying because when I run it locally it works just fine but the app store version doesnt. Maybe a new release after i try somethings

Comment: I'm releasing my first app later this week myself so I can relate :). I'm pretty sure you can debug a 'release' build, maybe that will give you a bit more parity with the AppStore version. Also deleting AsyncStorage on your test device if that's applicable / matching iOS versions, etc.  If you can replicate the error -- React Native Debugger will definitely help you from there. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

After Hours of debugging and starting with a fresh project I realized I had not installed [react native screens](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-screens). Oddly enough there was no error showing up in the expo crash logs and it was running perfectly. On both ios and android from expo go.
Had to set up [sentry](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-sentry/) in the project, unfortunately  Testflight also didn't bring up any entries. But thanks to sentry I was finnaly able to see the error `requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreen" was not found in the UIManager.`